# How to: Representing NULL in SQLite queries

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have a database winforms application using SQLite written in C#. I'm attempting to do some SQLite queries with the C# wrapper, but am having some issues with the query where I'm checking for NULL values. Here's the calling statement.

```
sqliteQuery.selectFromDatabase("*", "WHERE (FirstNotify = NULL) AND (SecondNotify != NULL) AND (ThirdNotify = NULL)");
```

And here's the code behind it.

```
public DataTable selectFromDatabase(String column, String filter)
    {
        string SQL = "SELECT " + column + " FROM SUBCONTRACTOR " + filter;
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

The query is not returning anything at all, when it should be returning a few records. Am I handling the NULL checks correctly? I've found a few other posts that use WHERE (VAR IS NULL) instead of using equals. I've tried both, but am unsure as to how to handle "not equals" when I was using "IS" instead of "equals". Anyone have any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony, Femaref: Thanks both of you! Changing to IS and IS NOT worked. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` when comparing equality/inequality to null.

Answer (score 1):

You already got it right - to compare for `NULL` you have to use `var is NULL`. if you want to compare for unequality, use `var is not NULL`.