Data retrieving and SQL database update
I'm trying to retrieve some data from an API and save them to a local database I created. All data come from Google Ads campaigns, and I need to make two separate calls because of their docs, but that's good. I take the data, mix them in a dataframe, and then call a second function to check if that specific row is already in the database to add or update the row properly.
To check if the row is already in the database, I need to look at these fields: ['date', 'campaign', 'keyword_text']. The problem is that keyword_text can be a value or be None (while the other two are always a value and can't be empty).
The save_to_database function is working for every other retrieving function, but when it faces the None value of keyword_text, it recognizes it's already there, but then it duplicates the entry in the database.
That's the function to retrieve the data:
def google_ads_retrieving(start_date, end_date):
    data_source = "google_ads"
    fields = FIELDS['google_ads']
    
    r = api_retrieving(data_source, fields, start_date, end_date)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        data_json = json.loads(r.text)
    else:
        st.error(f"Errore nel recupero dei dati da {data_source}: {str(r.text)}")
        return
    
    df = pd.json_normalize(data_json, record_path=["data"])
    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.date

    fields_conv = FIELDS['google_ads_conv']

    r_conv = api_retrieving(data_source, fields_conv, start_date, end_date)

    if r_conv.status_code == 200:
        data_conv_json = json.loads(r_conv.text)
    else:
        st.error(f"Errore nel recupero delle conversioni da {data_source}: {str(r.text)}")
        return
    
    df_conv = pd.json_normalize(data_conv_json, record_path=["data"])
    df_conv["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_conv["date"]).dt.date
    df_conv['conversions'] = pd.to_numeric(df_conv['conversions'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
    
    df = df.merge(df_conv, on=["datasource", "source", "account_id", "account_name", "date", "campaign", "keyword_text"], how="left")
    df['keyword_text'] = df['keyword_text'].fillna('').astype(str).str.strip()

    try:
        save_to_database(df, f"{data_source}_data", is_api=True)
        st.success(f"Dati da {data_source} salvati correttamente")
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Errore nel salvare i dati da {data_source}: {str(e)}")

That's the function to save data in the database:
def save_to_database(df, table_name, is_api=True):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('local_data.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    if is_api:
        if table_name == 'facebook_data':
            key_columns = ['date', 'campaign', 'adset_name', 'ad_name', 'age', 'gender']
        elif table_name == 'google_ads_data':
            key_columns = ['date', 'campaign', 'keyword_text']
        elif table_name == 'tiktok_data':
            key_columns = ['date', 'campaign', 'ad_group_name', 'ad_name']
        elif table_name == 'googleanalytics4_data':
            key_columns = ['date', 'campaign']
        else:
            st.warning(f"Tabella {table_name} non supportata nella funzione save_to_database. I dati potrebbero non essere salvati correttamente.")
            key_columns = ['date', 'campaign']
    else:
        key_columns = ['id']

    if 'keyword_text' in key_columns:
        df['keyword_text'] = df['keyword_text'].fillna('').astype(str).str.strip()

    cursor.execute(f"SELECT {', '.join(key_columns)} FROM {table_name}")
    existing_data = set()
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        existing_key = tuple(k if k is not None else '' for k in row)
        existing_data.add(existing_key)
    
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        key = tuple(row[col] for col in key_columns)
        key_str = tuple(k if pd.notnull(k) else '' for k in key)
        if key_str in existing_data:
            update_query = f"UPDATE {table_name} SET "
            update_query += ", ".join([f"{col} = ?" for col in df.columns if col not in key_columns])
            update_query += f" WHERE {' AND '.join([f'{col} = ?' for col in key_columns])}"
            update_values = [row[col] for col in df.columns if col not in key_columns] + list(key)
            cursor.execute(update_query, update_values)
        else:
            insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({', '.join(df.columns)}) VALUES ({', '.join(['?' for _ in df.columns])})"
            cursor.execute(insert_query, row.tolist())        
        existing_data.add(key_str)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

What am I missing here to make this work?

You're replacing None with an empty string. In the DB, the  corresponding value may be NULL, so the comparison won't work.

Oh, ok. So how could I write the code with the correct comparison? Is it in the key_string where I inserted ''? I'm still learning how to work with databases and I guess it's a long way

Let the database check for duplicates with insert ignore …, or insert … if not exists…. . Should be faster.

If the table can contain null values, use null-safe comparison. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56207567/comparing-two-potentially-null-values-in-sqlite-query

I'm feeling a little dumb. I've tried but I failed. If I change the = with IS in the update query, everything get duplicated, even the row that previously where rightfully updated
